# Angular material Mat Dialog: Test fail with Could not find column with id "dialogs"

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have created a MatDialog component and i'm using it inside another one.
It's working fine but i can't get the test on the component where i'm using the dialog to pass
Test fail : Error: Could not find column with id "dialogs".

My component that invoke the dialog :

```
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from '../../shared/modals/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';

constructor(private userService: UserService, private dialog: MatDialog) { }

openDialog(user: User): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { tille: 'Confirm box', msg: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user?' }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result === 'OK') {
        this.dataSource.deleteUsers(user, this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize, this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.input.nativeElement.value);
      }
    });
  }
```

The test

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {SharedModule} from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { ListUserComponent } from './list-user.component';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { GraphqlModuleModule } from '../../graphql-module/graphql-module.module';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

describe('ListUserComponent', () => {
  let component: ListUserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListUserComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, SharedModule, RouterTestingModule, GraphqlModuleModule],
      declarations: [ListUserComponent],
      providers: [UserService, { provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListUserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // UserService actually injected into the component
    // const userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);
    // Setup spy on the `getQuote` method
    // spyOn(userService, 'getUsers').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(getUsers));
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The ConfirmDialogComponent is the exports, declarations and entryComponents list of the SharedModule

Which versions of Angular, Material, OS, TypeScript, browsers are affected?

Angular: 5.2.1
Material: 5.1.0
Windows 10,

Comment: This error is usually related to a `mat-table`. Given that you use a paginator, I guess you have this too. How do you fix the columns of that array in your component ? At declaration, or in a function ?

Comment: I have found my probleme. I had actually nothing to do with MatDialog but with DataTable. One of the column was mistakenly changed to the value 'dialog'